# Organic Groups and Workbench or Revisioning together. Will this work?

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I'm building a D7 site using Organic Groups and would like some revisioning control.

Is it likely that something like [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) or [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) will work nicely with Organic Groups?

I'm interested in hearing of any good or bad experiences or advice.

I've done some initial tests and Workbench appeared to work okay. Of course the number of configurable options tends to explode with two node access modules. It gets quite complicated. The Revisioning module wasn't quite so smooth. I seemed to get into a situation where an item wasn't visible to a normal group member when it should be but it could be fixed if the author / moderator simply edited the item and saved without doing anything. Maybe I need to have another play with that.

These modules actually do a lot more than we need. We don't really need multiple roles for author, moderator etc. Mostly "all" we'd like is the ability for a user to edit and save an existing node but see what it looks like before making it public. The "Preview" button does that (sort of) but it would be nice to be able to save changes, take a break, and come back later. Also, the public view maybe in a panel so "Preview" doesn't really show the final result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We've built a D7 site with Organic Groups and Revisioning and have found that installing Organic Groups causes a pretty major problem with Revisioning in that the Author and Moderator roles cannot see unpublished content.  We've confirmed on a clean Drupal installation that Organic Groups Access Control is the cause of the issue.

The only workaround that we found was to check the Bypass Access Control checkbox for those roles.  That means those roles bypass all security checks on content on the site so they can edit/delete/publish any content.  That is an okay work around for our site but did present a problem when we wanted a separate moderator role for just one content type.

See this post for full details -> http://drupal.org/node/1494232

We are planning on looking at Workbench for a different D7 site because Revisioning and Rules isn't going to be sufficient for the workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to go with one of these options:

- [OG Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_workflow)
- [Workbench OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_og)

...depending on whether you prefer [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) or [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation).  To help with that decision, [What is the difference between the Workbench and Workflow modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29550/what-is-the-difference-between-the-workbench-and-workflow-modules) may be useful.

At the time of this writing, Workbench OG is more popular by a factor of 6.

There doesn't seem to be a good [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) solution because of [Revisioning and Organic Groups Access Control - requires rebuild perms all the time](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494232).