# journal website

Tags: nodes, files

I need to create a journal management website that will have

```
authors - who can submit journals to be published, 
reviewers  - who review submitted journals of the author,
subscribers - who can subscribe to journals that are published,
```

The site will have search for journals that will be listed with thumbnails, recent published journals

is this a job for drupal, what is the best and fast way to go?

the people that will be using this are non technical so using the admin of drupal is not good

Answer (score 4):

First let me remind you, the scope for the question is very vast. What I will try to do is list out pros and cons of using Drupal and provide you a general direction to start,

Firstly, yes Drupal is perfectly capable of handling sites of these type with efficiency and a large number of such sites and created using Drupal. But please do remember, Drupal is an open source CMS and dont expect to get everything ready and out of the box. Be prepared to get your hands dirty and try out a few stuffs.

But what Drupal will provide you is with an awesome API to ease your work and a set of very powerful contrib modules. in a nutshell, I think Drupal will be a great choice in your case.

Now a general direction and a few contrib modules you can start looking at:

1. [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) - this awesome module will help you to create all sorts of workflow for document creation, approval, and publishing.
2. [Subscriptions](https://drupal.org/project/subscriptions)

Now a word for your concern regarding Drupal backend, i agree with you it is a bit too much for non technical guys but with a pro that it is functionally solid. So what i usually tend to do is redesign the forms and create a dashboard like stuff for the non admins/content editors. So with a few sets of permissions, form layout change and css you can make that really usable for non technical guys.

Hope I could provide you with details you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Is this a job for drupal- Definitely yes

Q2. what is the best and fast way to go? - Depends on kind of resources you have to develop it and its always hard to say the best ;)

Q3. The people that will be using this are non technical so using the admin of drupal is not good? - Once it is developed, role of people will not be much more than creating a node/content.

Now come to, how drupal can be helpful,I agree to @new suggestions -
Modules that can be helpful for the development

For your content workflow

- [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation),[Workflow](https://drupal.org/project/workflow)
- [Difference between both modules.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29550/what-is-the-difference-between-the-workbench-and-workflow-modules)

For Subscriptions

- [Subscriptions](https://drupal.org/project/subscriptions), [Notifications](https://drupal.org/project/notifications), [Simple Subscrption](https://drupal.org/project/simple_subscription), [SimpleNews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews)
- which subscription module should be used, again depends on requirement and what module provides so preferably a module which has functionality close to requirement should be best option so you do not have a overkill module or module along which you have to custom code everything.

As a glance what you will get out of box for workflow of your content.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd0AWNKtgLw
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFENFkwneGo

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into the Open Publish Distribution, which can give you a headstart on some issues that can be tough to figure out like multiple authors on an article, for example.

https://drupal.org/project/openpublish

http://openpublishapp.com/

Try a demo (20 min limit) at http://simplytest.me by entering openpublish in the box and selecting the 7.x version

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* do this with Drupal, you may want to look at [Open Journal Systems](http://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/) as well.  This is a free and open source "out-of-the-box" WCMS dedicated to the task of publishing multiple (peer-)reviewed journals on a single web-site.

> Open Journal Systems (OJS) is a journal management and publishing system that has been developed by the Public Knowledge Project through its federally funded efforts to expand and improve access to research.
>
> OJS Features:
>
> 1. OJS is installed locally and locally controlled.
> 2. Editors configure requirements, sections, review process, etc.
> 3. Online submission and management of all content.
> 4. Subscription module with delayed open access options.
> 5. Comprehensive indexing of content part of global system.
> 6. Reading Tools for content, based on field and editors’ choice.
> 7. Email notification and commenting ability for readers.
> 8. Complete context-sensitive online Help support.

You can do all of the above with Drupal, but you will have to do a lot of customization that you get by default with OJS.

I am a Drupal developer, but I also run a peer-reviewed journal. I have choosen OJS rather than Drupal for that *specific task*.